# InnoDB "autoextend" function

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I'm very confused about use of InnoDB. 
I've a server with limited storage and I've read that InnoDB tables creates default size table at 10MB autoextend.

I don't understand "autoextend" function. If I exceed 10MB for one table, MySQL automatically increase memory (10Mb + 10MB)?

So, can I change default limit for any table?

For example:

- Table1 = default 10MB;
- Table2 = default 0.5MB;
- etc...

is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

#### Updated for MySQL 8.0

If you don't enable `innodb_file_per_table` or specify a tablespace for a table explicitly, InnoDB data will be stored in a set of files called a system tablespace.

Latest versions of MySQL enable `innodb_file_per_table` by default.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-file-per-table-tablespaces.html

> InnoDB creates tables in file-per-table tablespaces by default. This behavior is controlled by the `innodb_file_per_table` variable. Disabling `innodb_file_per_table` causes InnoDB to create tables in the system tablespace.

When this fileset has no free space left, the size of the last file in the set is increased in chunks specified by the `autoextend` parameter, which is 8MB by default.

`InnoDB` will only grow the last file in the set.

If you use `innodb_file_per_table` then each table uses its own tablespace. It is always stored in one file (residing in the db directory).

This file grows in chunks of configurable size, which by default is 4M.

In latest versions of MySQL, you can also create tablespaces explicitly and assign tables to them. Tablespaces that you create explicitly are called general tablespaces. You can configure the auto-extend option for them as well.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-file-per-table-tablespaces.html

> From MySQL 8.0.23, the amount by which a file-per-table or general tablespace is extended is configurable by specifying the `AUTOEXTEND_SIZE` option. Configuring a larger extension size can help avoid fragmentation and facilitate ingestion of large amounts of data.

Comment: Ok, How can I check size of this file? If I have 18 table, should I have 18*10MB = 180MB? Where I can set innodb_file_per_table? I have to set it when I perform query: "CREATE TABLE table1 .... ENGINE=InnoDB"?

Comment: @Cecco: find it in your `MySQL` data directory. By default it is called `ibdata1`. This file grows automatically as you add new data to the tables, it is not necessary to allocate the space in advance.

Comment: @Cecco: you can set `innodb_file_per_table` under `[mysqld]` section of your config file. On `*NIX` it is usually located at `/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: I'm on Windows system. I've my.ini file, but I don't find entry innodb_file_per_table. I've another file named "my-innodb-heavy-4G.ini" that has entry "innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend".

Comment: Any link to official documentation ?